# counter example of Jensen's inequality?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $([0,10],\sigma([0,10]),\mu)$ be measure space where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. Consider $A=[0,5]\subset[0,1]$, and $f=\mathbb{1}_{A}$, then we have $\|f\|^p_p = \mu(A) = 5$ for any $p\ge1$.

$$\begin{align*}
\|f \|^2_2 &= \int |f|^2\,d\mu = \int ((|f|^2)^{3/2})^{2/3}\,d\mu\\
& \le \left(\int |f|^3\,d\mu\right)^{2/3} = \left(\int |f|^2\,d\mu\right)^{2/3}\\
& \le \cdots \le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\int |f|^2\,d\mu\right)^{({2/3})^{n}} = 1
\end{align*}
 $$
when $\|f\|^2_2 = 5$.

Probably I made a mistake somewhere, I hope someone tells me where. Thanks.

Comment: Jensen's inequality applies to *probability* measures, so $\mu(X) = 1$. This is not the case.

Comment: @user296602 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align*}
\int \left(\left(|f|^2\right)^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}\,d\mu \le \left[\mu([0,10])\right]^{1/3}\left(\int |f|^3\,d\mu\right)^{2/3}
\end{align*}

Comment: even so, if I keep iterating the process, then I will get $5\le 1$, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. You get $(\mu([0,10]))^{1/3\times \sum_{n\ge 0} (2/3)^n}$...

Comment: I see, understood. Thanks